# Why does the regex \pL+\pM+ not work with English?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, utf-8

Why does the regex `\pL+\pM+` not work with English?

Why does the below first example results false wherein the second one results true?

```
System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("suren") 
                .asCharBuffer().toString().matches("\\PL+\\PM+"));

System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("स्वागत") 
                .asCharBuffer().toString().matches("\\PL+\\PM+"));
```

Basically i need a regular expression to **restrict only unicode characters(any language in the world)** in a string.

Comment: "only unicode characters"? That makes no sense. If you encode your string in UTF-8 it will have nothing other than Unicode characters in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
"^[\\p{Letter&}\\p{Mark}]+$"
```

Your regex *requires* a mark (`\PM+`), whereas you only want to *allow* it. Also note the anchors.

On a general note: I'd recommend to use the long forms of the Unicode character properties. It makes the expression more readable.